# Gegl color-to-alpha does not remove the white color like GIMP does

Tags: bash, image-processing, ubuntu-12.04, gimp, gegl

### Color to Alpha

The color-to-alpha operation is when a color is taken from all the pixels in the image and converted to transparent, this is especially useful to extract hand written or free drawing from a fully white paper.

### The Command Line

Below is basic GEGL code to convert the white color to alpha, it used to work on Ubuntu 12.04, but after re-installing it, it looks like there is bug in GEGL.

I'm not sure what the previous setup was but the command line is mostly the same:

```
~/gegl/bin/gegl --xml '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gegl>
    <node operation="gegl:color-to-alpha">
    <params>
        <param name="color">white</param>
    </params>
    </node>    
    <node operation="gegl:load" id="clone0">
        <params>
            <param name="path">input.png</param>
        </params>
    </node>
</gegl>
' --output gegl-output.png
```

### Example on the Operation and the Gegl Error

The **input** image being used.

[image: Input]

The GIMP correct (i.e. desired) output, it used to work the same with GEGL.

[image: GIMP Output]

The current GEGL incorrect output.

[image]

Environment and Versions:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Babl 0.1.10 ([this one from ftp](http://ftp.gtk.org/pub/babl/0.1/babl-0.1.10.tar.bz2))
- Gegl 0.2.0 ([this one from ftp](ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gegl/0.2/gegl-0.2.0.tar.bz2))
- Other packages from Ubuntu 12.04 repository:

  - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  - imagemagick
  - libpng12-dev
  - libpango1.0-dev
  - intltool
  - libjpeg8-dev
  - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev

The gegl and babl are installed using the following command lines, because [GIMP 2.8 is also installed](http://www.maketecheasier.com/upgrade-to-gimp-2-8-in-ubuntu/2012/05/04) and using another version of GEGL:

```
$ tar -jxvf babl-0.1.10.tar.bz2
$ cd babl-0.1.10/
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/gegl
$ make
$ make install
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/gegl/lib/pkgconfig"
$ cd ..
$ tar -jxvf gegl-0.2.0.bz2
$ cd gegl-0.2.0/
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/gegl
$ make
$ make install
```

**Note**: he images are best to be opened with GIMP to see the alpha Chanel.

### What I Have Tried

1. I tried to uninstall the gegl and babl that comes with GIMP 2.8, but still, gegl don't work properly.
2. Check the answer, I did solve it while writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install babl and gegl from their git repo. `git://git.gnome.org/babl` and `git://git.gnome.org/gegl`. It solved the problem (most probably a gegl bug).

Comment: Did installing the current development options resolved it for you?